# SQL - Return a value if all rows that have the same "order number" in one column have the same "slot" in another

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table `oeordhdr_sql` that holds all information for an order using `Ord_No` as a unique ID. In another table `wsPKG` I have information stored per pallet. A pallet can be associated to be shipped out on a specific order in which case it gets a value in `Org_Ord_No` to associate it to the order in `oeordhdr_sql`. I have an `INNER JOIN` with an `ltrim` on both to match the pallet to the order. Since there can be multiple pallets associated to one order we move each pallet to a Bin (`Bin_No`) called `TRK` to show that it has been shipped.

So far I have this code

```
SELECT oeordhdr_sql.ord_no, wsPKG.Bin_no
FROM wsPKG
INNER JOIN oeordhdr_sql ON LTRIM(wsPKG.Org_Ord_no) = LTRIM(oeordhdr_sql.ord_no) 
WHERE wsPKG.Bin_no = 'TRK'
```

Which returns multiple lines for the same order.

```
   23708    TRK     
   23769    TRK     
   23769    TRK      
   23769    TRK     
   23769    TRK     
   23708    TRK     
   23708    TRK
```

I would like to be able to return a value for my shipping manager to show when all pallets associated to a specific order are located in TRK. That value could be Shipped. Eventually I would also have a status of Loading for if some are in TRK but not all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want a `GROUP BY` and `HAVING`:

```
SELECT oh.ord_no
FROM wsPKG p INNER JOIN
     oeordhdr_sql oh
     ON ltrim(p.Org_Ord_no) = ltrim(oh.ord_no) 
GROUP BY oh.ord_no
HAVING MIN(p.Bin_no) = 'TRK' AND MIN(p.Bin_no) = MAX(p.Bin_no)
```

This returns all the `oh.ord_no`s where all bin numbers are `'TRK'` (it ignores `NULL`s, so if the data has `NULL`s you might want to specify what to do with those bin numbers.

Note:  The `JOIN` condition is suspicious.  There should be no reason to use `TRIM()` on `JOIN` keys between related tables.  If the keys are numbers, this is meaningless.  If the keys are strings, they should be stored without leading or trailing spaces.

Comment: I agree on the JOIN condition but it was the only way I could get it to communicate. I will need to look into it some more. This returns the orders that had all pallets put on TRK. How would I then see if this specific order is in this list then show SHIPPED?

Comment: @TTarrier . . . I don't understand your comment.  The question is:  "I would like to be able to return a value for my shipping manager to show when all pallets associated to a specific order are located in TRK."  If you have a different question, it should be asked as a new question.

Comment: The sentence after that stated what I was asking:"That value could be Shipped." Should I still ask it as a separate question?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
Select DISTINCT OS.ord_no, WP.Bin_no
FROM wsPKG WP
LEFT JOIN oeordhdr_sql OS on ltrim(WP.Org_Ord_no)=ltrim(OS.ord_no) AND WP.Bin_no='TRK'
```

HTH

Thanks.